# Relation between weak * topology of $X^*$ and relative norm topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space.

what is the relation between the weak* topology of $X^*$ and the topology of $X^*$ inherited from $BC(X,\mathbb C)$ (space of all bounded, continuous, complex valued functions with supremum norm $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$) ?

Comment: The condition $\Vert x\Vert\leq 1$ for all $x\in X$ is impossible if $X\neq\{0\}$. Because if $\Vert x\Vert\neq 0$, then $1\geq \Vert r x\Vert=r\Vert x\Vert$ for all $r>0$, which is impossible.

Comment: @Littlefield Thanks. Is there any relation between these two topologies for a normed space $X$?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "relation". The topology you describe is called the norm topology on $X^*$, this is never equal to the weak* topology except in the case that $X$ is finite dimensional. Indeed the weak* topology is never induced by a norm except in the case of finite dimensions!

Comment: @s.harp Thank you. I mean by "relation", equality of topologies or one of the topologies includes the other one.

Answer (score 1):

The weak* topology is the coarsest/weakest topology on $X^*$ that makes the elements $X$ into continuous functionals on $X^*$ via:
$$x:X^*\to\Bbb C, \ x^*\mapsto x^*(x)$$
It is easy to see that the norm topology also makes the elements of $X$ continous functionals on $X^*$, so the norm topology is finer/stronger than the weak* topology. But they are never equal unless $X$ is finite dimensional.